# php header force download returning unusable mp3

Tags: php, header

i have been working on this for 5 days now... tearing down code and rebuilding it. I am trying to force a mp3 file download. When it has no special characters ( ampersand, quote, apostrophe), the download works fine. I loose all the metadata in the file, but the file downloads and is playable.
This is my download script for file download:

```
header('Content-type: audio/mpeg');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="TraxXMP3_'.$file.'"');
readfile($file);
   exit;
```

My humble guess is the data from the database is not being returned/sanitized correctly. But unsure how.i have tried this:

```
$var =  str_replace("'","%27", $var);
$var =  str_replace("%27", "'" , $var);
$var = htmlentities($var,ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8');
$var = html_entity_decode($var,ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8');
```

All of these will allow input and retrieval from database. it will display in the database as the modified string, and back to the html page. All other non-escaped files will download without issue. Only when there is escaped code does it fail.
Output files vary with the string escaping. Results like... file is transfered, but no content. Or, file is returned with unusable string (part of the filename without the mp3 extension).

This is the whole file download header file:

```
if(isset($_GET['file'])){
$file = $_GET['file'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM main_lib WHERE file_name='.$file.' LIMIT 1";
$query = mysqli_query($db_conn, $sql) or die (mysqli_error()); 
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) { 
$count_dl            = $row['count_dl'];
}
//mysqli_free_result($query);
mysqli_query($db_conn, "UPDATE main_lib SET count_dl='$count_dl'+1 WHERE file_name='$file'");
/**
* 
*   EMAIL SCRIPT HERE
* 
*/
mysqli_free_result($query);
$file =     cleanVarsDn($file);
    header('Content-type: audio/mpeg');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="TraxXMP3_'.$file.'"');
    readfile('../data/lib/'.$file);
    exit;
}
```

This is my string escape file:

```
function cleanVarsUp($var){
    //$var = htmlentities($var,ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8');
    //$var =  str_ireplace("\"",  "&quot;", $var);
    $var =  str_replace("'","%27", $var);
    return $var;
}
function cleanVarsDn($var){
    //$var =  str_ireplace("&apos;",  "'", $var);
    //$var = html_entity_decode($var,ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8');
    $var =  str_replace("%27", "'" , $var);
    return $var;
}
```

Commented out lines are what i have tried. Note... this script DOES work. Just not with unsanitized Data.
I am totally lost here. NOT a rookie programmer, but not a pro either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my issue. I didnt add a filesize to it,so it wasnt reading the length of the file. Added these 2 lines and works flawlessly

```
$size = filesize('../data/lib/'.$file);
header('Content-Length: ' . $size);
```